# keeping login sessions with cakephp view caching

Tags: caching, cakephp-2.0

I use view caching in my cakephp based cms with generates the cached views for frontend usage.
The frontend checks whether a user is logged or not to show edit options. It works without the view caching enabled, but when enabled it loses the session.

I've put the session code in no cache tags (index.ctp), but there's no session available

```
<!--nocache-->
$_SESSION['Auth']['User']['username'];
<!--/nocache-->
```

How can keep the login session when using view caching?

Answer (score 1):

The anwser is to use the cakephp session helper instead of the native php $_SESSION variable

```
<!--nocache-->
$this->session->read('Auth.user.name');
<!--/nocache-->
```